# 2 Column JTable for filenames. Autoupdate when more files are added to a list of files?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am making a file converter. I will have JButton's to Add and Remove files from the list. When adding a file, it'll bring up a JFileChooser(or something) and return a list of files. Will I need to repopulate the entire table each time I add/remove files? If I have to resolve to that, what is the best approach?

When I didn't have two columns, I used JListModel + JList< File>. Is there a similar approach for using JTables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't have to repopulate the entire table. Just use DefaultTableModel.addRow(). JTable automatically creates an instance of DefaultTableModel.

Check this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way is writing your own `TableModel`. If you inherit from [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), I think that it's a convenient way to use the [*observer design pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). If you want to update the table, call `fireTableXxx()` methods.